# Apply theme color to regular HTML element using Stylus

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, stylus

I want to change color of regular HTML element (let's say `span`) to one of theme colors. How can I refer to this color (primary/accent/etc) from Stylus file?

Almost all the answers that I found describe how to do this using SCSS but it seems the provided solutions do not work in case Stylus.

Answer (score 0):

primary,accent,... are class, so you need use ngClass or class.primary

```
<span [ngClass]="variable">...</span>
//and 
variable='myClass'

//or
<span [ngClass]="{'primary':condition}">...</span>
//or
<span [class.primary]="condition">...</span>
```

You use [ngStyle] or [style.property] in the way

```
<span [ngStyle]="myStyle">..</span>
e.g.
myStyle={'background-color':red,width:'1rem'}
//or

<span [ngStyle]="{color:variable}">...</span>
//and
variable='red'

//or
<span [style.color]="'red'">...</span>

//or
<span [style.color]="variable">...</span>
//and 
variable='red'
```

you can see more examples in, e.g. [this link](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I cannot find class "primary" or "accent". Instead Angular provides classes "mat-primary" and "mat-accent" but they can be applied only to limited set of HTML elements.